# How can my browser display special character in html correctly?

Tags: html

My HTML script includes some special characters, for example, `<` (less than), or `'` (single quote). For `<` (lt), the code represent it as `&amp;lt;` and for `'` (single quote), the code is `&amp;#39`.

The browser cannot show them correctly. Instead, it shows `&lt` for `&amp;lt;` and `&#39` for `&amp;#39`. Is there any generic way to show these character correctly? I don't wanna replace all the `&amp;` with `&` in the source code. Thanks.

Comment: The browser is showing them correctly. `&amp;` HTML means `&` as text. `&lt;` as HTML is the correct code for `<` as text. `&amp;lt;` as HTML is correct for `&lt;` as text. You have a case of double encoding. How did you get to this state, and why do you not want to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The correct HTML character entities for `<`, `>`, `'`, and `&`  are...  `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;`, and `&amp;` **...or...** `&#60;`, `&#62;`, `&#39;`, and `&#38;` respectively. It sounds like if anything,  your browser is correcting your mistakes.

Comment: Is this static HTML, or is some sort of content management system or framework involved?

Comment: @Amadan Thx a lot for your explanation~ I extract the HTML code from JIRA api, and the HTML code that I got shows `<` as `&amp;lt;`. I want to show it correctly in browser as `<`. Since the HTML code is generated automatically, I don't why the case of double encoding happening.

Comment: @ceejayoz this is static HTML

Comment: How are you using the JIRA api? Are you doing this in PHP, or how do you generate the html? Please include the code for that and tag you post with the appropriate programming language tags.

Answer (score 0):

The entity name for `<` (less than) is `&lt;`
If you want to use two entities together then you have to include the `&` like
 `&amp;&lt;`

To know more about entities : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp